Error RequestHeaderSectionTooLarge After Signing In Using NextAuth with AzureADProvider
I have implemented authentication in my application using NextAuth.js with the AzureADProvider. The authentication flow completes successfully, but after signing in, I encounter a RequestHeaderSectionTooLarge error. This error seems to occur due to large request headers generated during the authentication process. I am looking for guidance on how to resolve this issue.
Implementation Details:

Framework: Next.js
Authentication: NextAuth.js with AzureADProvider
Error: RequestHeaderSectionTooLarge
The error occurs after the user successfully signs in using their Azure AD credentials. Here is the relevant part of my pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js configuration:

import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import AzureADProvider from "next-auth/providers/azure-ad"

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    AzureADProvider({
      clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET,
      tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID
    })
  ],
  // Additional NextAuth configuration if applicable
})

Steps to Reproduce:

Start the Next.js application.

Navigate to the login page.

Sign in using Azure AD credentials.

Encounter the RequestHeaderSectionTooLarge error.

I have reviewed the Azure AD application manifest and tried limiting the groupMembershipClaims to reduce token size, but the issue persists.

I have attempted to adjust the server settings to allow for larger headers, but I would prefer a solution that involves reducing the header size, if possible.
Questions:

What configurations can I adjust in NextAuth or Azure AD to prevent large headers from being generated?

Are there best practices when configuring NextAuth with AzureADProvider to handle large groups or claim sizes?
I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.



I successfully signed in and did not get any errors. See these output images in browser and VS code Terminal output.

The RequestHeaderSectionTooLarge error is typically caused by excessively large HTTP headers, often due to large tokens or numerous claims. This is a common issue when integrating with Azure AD, especially if the user is a member of many groups or has numerous claims.
Steps to fix the above issue:
Minimize the Token Size: Azure AD tokens can become very large if they contain numerous claims, especially group claims.
Check the below steps to reduce the token size:
Limit Group Claims
By default, Azure AD includes all group memberships in the token, which can result in a very large token. You can change this behavior to only include groups relevant to your application or use group filtering.
In Azure AD application registration, go to Token configuration > add a group claim and select "Security groups" or "Groups assigned to the application". Then, select the appropriate format, preferably Group IDs instead of Group names.
Application Manifest: Edit the application manifest to control the group claims with the information below.
"optionalClaims": {
  "idToken": [],
  "accessToken": [],
  "saml2Token": []
},
"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"

Code :
pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js :
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import AzureADProvider from "next-auth/providers/azure-ad";

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    AzureADProvider({
        clientId: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET,
        tenantId: process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile }) {
      if (account && profile) {
        token.id = profile.id;
        token.email = profile.email;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user.id = token.id;
      session.user.email = token.email;
      return session;
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
});

pages/index.js :
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react";

export default function Home() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  if (session) {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Welcome {session.user.email}</h1>
        <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
      </>
    );
  }
  return (
    <>
      <h1>You are not signed in</h1>
      <button onClick={() => signIn("azure-ad")}>Sign in with Azure AD</button>
    </>
  );
}

pages/_app.js :
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import '../styles/globals.css';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}
export default MyApp;

.env.local :
AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID=<client_ID>
AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET=<client_Secret>
AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID=<tenant_ID>
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=<secret> //openssl rand -base64 32 is the command to gerenrate a secret

Output :

Browser Output :




@user25152936 Have you tried the solution I provided?
